# creating a sparse matrix from dictionary with tuple keys

Tags: python, dictionary, matrix, tuples, sparse-matrix

I have the following problem and I was hoping that someone could help me out here:
I have a dictionary with tuples as keys d={(1,2):1, (2,1):1, (1,3):1, (3,1):1, (2,3):1, (3,2):1, (1,4):1, (4,1):1, (2,4):1, (4,2):1, (3,4):1, (4,3):1}
Now, I would like to create a matrix that is appropriate to the tuples, with four rows and four columns. In my head, I imagine it likes this (sorry if that seems a little messy):

```
 1 2 3 4
```

1:  0 1 1 1

2:  1 0 1 1

3:  1 1 0 1

4:  1 1 1 0

Where the four numbers a the top (1 2 3 4) represent the columns corresponding to the numbers in the tuples and the same goes for the numbers on the left (from top to bottom 1 2 3 4) for the rows.

The output should look like this:

```
array([[0, 1, 1, 1],
   [1, 0, 1, 1],
   [1, 1, 0, 1],
   [1, 1, 1, 0]])
```

Unfortunately, I have absolutely no idea how to get the sparse matrix from my head into a proper code (python 3), and it seems like I reached the end of my wisdom, although I am sure that there must be a simple answer to this.
If anybody could help me out here, I would really appreciate it.
Thanks in advance

Comment: SO is not a coding service. Start with some coding. The community will help you, but it is not here to solve the problem for you. This question will probably lead to downvotes.

Comment: what do you mean ?  I honestly had a problem that I felt I could not solve on my own, even if my life depended on it. Start some coding?  I will gladly post the entire code that is relevant to the problem, if thats what you mean.

Answer (score 0):

A one-line solution, assuming you want to fill your array with 0's in the places not specified in the dictionary:

```
 np.asarray([[(d[(x,y)] if (x,y) in d else 0) for y in range(1,5)] for x in range(1,5)])
```

Output:

```
array([[0, 1, 1, 1],
       [1, 0, 1, 1],
       [1, 1, 0, 1],
       [1, 1, 1, 0]])
```

A more laborious but maybe easier-to-understand approach would be to initialize an empty array of zeros, and then go through it and replace 0 with 1 at each position that appears in the dictionary.

Comment: thanks so much. really simple and works flawlessly. i knew there had to be a simple solution, but for some reason, it eluded me ;)

Comment: Glad to help. If the answer was helpful for you, please accept it.